# R - order() messes up order every other run

Tags: r, sorting

I am working with a mandatory assignment for school and trying to sort my data frame based on one of the columns with order(see code). It worked perfectly the first time, however the next time i ran the code, the order got messed up. And now, every other time i run the code it is right ordered one time, and messed up the next time. Probably just some small mistake, or some misunderstanding about how variable work in R, can anyone help?

If you run the code, you can see easily that plot changes from a nice red curve, to a spiderweb chaos, from run to run.

```
dataset <- read.table("https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/STK2100/v19/mandatoryassignments-exam/data.dat")

set.seed(1)
samplesize <- round(nrow(dataset)/2)
samp <- sample(seq_len(nrow(dataset)), size = samplesize)
training <- dataset[samp, ]
test <- dataset[-samp, ]
training <- training[order(x),]
test <- test[order(x),]

attach(training)
library(caret)
ctrl <- trainControl(method="cv",number = 5)
knn <- train(y ~ x, data = training, metric = "Rsquared", method = "knn", trControl = ctrl)

knn
y.pred = predict(knn,newdata = x)
plot(training)
lines(x, y.pred, col='red')
```

I solved the problem by exchanging

```
training <- training[order(x),]
#with
training <- training[order(training$x),]
```

Comment: I would suggest not to `attach`

Comment: I tried that, but got a some error message, however I realised that when ordering the data i use x and not training$x, and that was the problem

Comment: It's still best to avoid `attach`, it can create some problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is likely caused by multiple `attach` statements. Lets take an example to try an pin-point the problem.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 6
DT <- data.frame(letters = LETTERS[1:6], numbers = 6:1, x = sample(1:6))
head(DT)

  letters numbers x
1       A       6 2
2       B       5 6
3       C       4 3
4       D       3 4
5       E       2 1
6       F       1 5
```

Now i assume that x is contained in your data, but more likely you have a variable stored somewhere. It is not included in your code so i am only guessing, and in any way it has be a vector of `length <= nrow(DT)`.

## Problem 1: `attach(x)`

Now you are saying that your problem happens every other time, so this seems to be the most likely reason. From your code, if x is contained in `DT`, you are attaching your data.frame before running your code:

```
attach(DT)
DT <- DT[order(x),]
head(DT)

  letters numbers x
5       E       2 1
1       A       6 2
3       C       4 3
4       D       3 4
6       F       1 5
2       B       5 6
```

This correctly orders our data.frame.

now if you run the code again, most often people clear memory by running `rm(list=ls())`, to clear all variables. If you do ordering should work out fine, but most R users suggest not using `attach`, and lets just quickly show one reason why:

```
rm(list=ls()) #remove everything we can see
x
print(x)

[1] 2 6 3 4 1 5
```

As is suprising to most new R users, 'x' 'letters' and 'numbers' still exist as variables. In order to remove these you will have to run `detach(DT)` even after running `rm(list=ls())`. It is fine using `attach` as long as one remembers this, and the data is not too large.

Now consider the possibility that you rerun your code. You `attach` statement is after your `order` statement, as such the following things will happen at each run:

1. First run: you get an error as there is no attached `x`.
2. No error, as `x` has been attached `DT` is now going to be sorted, and then attached again
3. At the third run, if you have not detached `DT`, the sorted `x` will be attached at `pos = 2` and will thus be used to order your data (but `x` is already sorted, so nothing happens)

For (1) note that in your code

```
training <- training[order(x),]
test <- test[order(x),]

attach(training)
```

As such attach comes after order, which will likely cause an error the first time your run.

For (2 - 3), it is easier to visualize: Re-running your code 2 more times (after the first run), will be similar to running the code below. This visualizes the 'problem every second time'. In the code i have removed less relevant errors and warnings produces for readability (but there are multiple)

```
for(i in 1:3){ 
    try(
        {
            #Create dataset
            set.seed(1)
            n <- 6
            DT <- data.frame(letters = LETTERS[1:6], numbers = 6:1, x = sample(1:6))
            print(x)
            DT <- DT[order(x),] #order data (note the first time it is not attached, eg. produces an error)
            print(DT)
        }
    )
    attach(DT) #attach the current data
}
```

> Error in order(x) : object 'x' not found

Second print: (first one fails)

```
>x
2 6 3 4 1 5
>DT
  letters numbers x
5       E       2 1
1       A       6 2
3       C       4 3
4       D       3 4
6       F       1 5
2       B       5 6
```

Third print:

```
>x
1 2 3 4 5 6
>DT
  letters numbers x
1       A       6 2
2       B       5 6
3       C       4 3
4       D       3 4
5       E       2 1
6       F       1 5
```

The first time we get an error, because `x` did not exist (was not found). The next time x has been attached from `DT`, and everything works out fine. The third time, x was attached from the sorted `DT` and nothing happened.

Note from the output that the `x` is sorted in the third print, as it is the attached `x` from the second print. Therefore sorting it will not change the ordering of it. This is likely your problem.

Now i have attached the data multiple times, and an important note, that is the reason for many experienced R users avoiding the use of `attach` is all the warnings it produces. lets try running attach again:

```
>attach(DT)

The following objects are masked from DT (pos = 3):

    letters, numbers, x

The following objects are masked from DT (pos = 4):

    letters, numbers, x

The following objects are masked from DT (pos = 5):

    letters, numbers, x

The following object is masked from package:base:

    letters
```

This warning is telling you, that multiple attachs has been run, and that multiple variables exist under the same names (currently holding the same data). It even tells us how many: `pos = 5`, basically there are 4 layers of variables and the global environment:

1. The global environment `(pos = 1)`
2. The fourth attachment, that we just ran `(pos = 2)`
3. the third attachment from the loop `(pos = 3)`
4. The second attachment from the loop `(pos = 2)`
5. the first attachment from the loop `(pos = 3)`

This is yet another reason to remember to `detach` after you are finished using your attached data (or `detach` repeatably `pos - 1` times if you attached it multiple times).

```
replicate(4, detach(DT))
```

In principle if you have enough memory, and you remember to `detach` your data, everything works out fine. But one should keep in mind that using `rm(list = ls())` does **not** detach your frame, as illustrated below:

```
attach(DT)
rm(list=ls())
x

>2 6 3 4 1 5
```

Detach is thus a mandatory step of any procedure using `attach`.

For your specific problem, moving `attach(training)` up top and adding a `detach(training)` down at the bottom should fix the problem.